# Converting string into negative float number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, implicit-conversion

The negative numeric value I'm getting from the back-end application is formatted according to our internal configuration (UI user profile). In other words, for value **-23.79879** my xml input may be
`<myNumber>-23.79879</myNumber>` or `<myNumber>23,79879-</myNumber>` or other 
and I can't turn the formatting off. 
The assumption is that the formats are "standard", normally used for localization.
I'm looking to do something like:

```
convertStringToNumber(numberString, formatString, slignPosition)
```

Comment: Will numbers have a thousands separator as well as a decimal separator? E.g., could there be `-2,123.79879` (`,` = thousands separator) or `-2.123,79879` (`.` = thousands separator)? If they can, then you'll have to make an assumption if only one of the symbols (`,` or `.`) is present and happens to be in a valid location for either (such as `1,234`, which could be "one and 234 hundreths" or "one thousand two hundred and thirty-four").

Comment: You *have* filed a bug report with the suppliers of the back-end application, right? :-) APIs should send data in an unambiguous, consistent format. Localized forms are for users to consume, not software.

Comment: I definitely filed a bug, but there is very little chance it would be fixed any soon :-(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with formatString, but maybe something like this?:

```
function convertStringToNumber(num){
    num=num.split(',').join('.');
    if(num.indexOf('-') ==num.length-1){
        num='-'+num.substr(0,num.length-1);
    }
    return parseFloat(num) || null;
}



console.log(convertStringToNumber("-23.79879"))
console.log(convertStringToNumber("23,79879-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to expose the parsing rule from the backend, which obviously knows the format. This can be done in many ways, but one easy way i am fond of is simply to break down all the moving parts of the format, define properties for each on an object and then expose that object to the parser.

The object could look something like this:

```
var opts =  {
  thousandsSeparator: ',',
  decimalSeparator: '.',
  negativeSign: '-'
};
```

Then pass that object into a parsing function like this:

```
function parseNumber(opts, str) {
      var isNegative = false;
        if(str.indexOf(opts.negativeSign) != -1) {
            isNegative = true;
            str = str.replace(opts.negativeSign,'');
        }
        var parts = str.split(opts.thousandsSeparator).join('').split(opts.decimalSeparator);
        var num = 1 * parts[0];
        var deci = 1 * parts[1];
        if(deci) num += deci /  Math.pow(10,parts[1].length);
        return isNegative ? -1 * num : num;
}
```

You would then call it like thuis:

parseNumber(opts,'2,345.234-'); //-2345.234